# How do i unset specified session

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I wonder how i unset a specified session.

```
$array = array(
                'Name' => 'Jhon',
                'Age' => '19',
                'Remark' => 'Tests'
            );
$this->session->set_userdata('registrasi',$array);
```

I know i can delete session with

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('registrasi');
```

How do i delete `Remark` ? so the last result will be like this.

```
 'Name' => 'Jhon',
 'Age' => '19'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unset_userdata()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#removing-session-data)

```
$this->session->unset_userdata()
```

In You case

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('Remark');
```

---

I tired this with an my own example. Check below

**This is my session**

```
$session = array(
    'id' => $result[0]['id'],
    'username'  => $name,
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

**Printing session**

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
    [session_id] => 4cc6794ab4d1ee062e377945c92148dc 
    [ip_address] => ::1 
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 
    [last_activity] => 1464104585 
    [user_data] => 
        [id] => 1 
        [username] => Admin 
        [logged_in] => 1 
        [flash:new:success] => Welcome Admin 
)
```

**And im going to remove *`username`* from the above session**

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('username');
```

**And printing back**

```
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
    [session_id] => 4cc6794ab4d1ee062e377945c92148dc 
    [ip_address] => ::1 
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 
    [last_activity] => 1464104585 
    [user_data] => 
        [id] => 1 
        [logged_in] => 1 
        [flash:new:success] => Welcome Admin 
    )
```

---

> > ***So this tested and works well***

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it.

```
public function index()
{

    $array = array(
        'Name' => 'Jhon',
        'Age' => '19',
        'Remark' => 'Tests'
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata('registrasi',$array);

    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}

public function delete()
{

    $i = "Tests";

    $del = $this->session->userdata('registrasi');
    $index = array_search($i, $del);
    unset($del[$index]);
    $this->session->set_userdata('registrasi', $del);
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
}
```